# How to check who stopped an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way (for example in CLI) to check what user stopped an instance?
There is some data in the console:

```
State transition reason: User initiated (2017-07:24 10:15:42 GMT)
State transition reason message: Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown
```

Answer (score 5):

[Amazon CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) can be used to create an **Audit Trail** of most API requests made to AWS. It records the time, IP address, user and request details.

However, you will need to configure CloudTrail before it captures this information because you will need to **specify an Amazon S3 bucket** where it can store the data. Therefore, you won't be able to see who stopped your instance this time, but if you configure CloudTrail you'll be able to do it in future.

Comment: This is right on! -- CloudTrail logging tells you everything, regardless of whether the action was taken by a user in the web interface, via the CLI, or programmatically in some code. New accounts should always enable this!

Comment: Cloudtrail also only has 90 days of data.

Comment: @runamok If you specifically create a Trail in CloudTrail, then you can access Event data beyond 90 days by using the logs stored in Amazon S3. See: [Viewing CloudTrail events in the CloudTrail console - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html)